# JSP file not running

Tags: java, jsp

i have created one jsp file but it doesn't running in any way..!!

it gives `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ServletException`.

here is the complete error message.

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:272)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I am using `Eclipse Helios SR1` and `Apache Tomcat 6.0`,
with `JDK 1.6.0`.

Comment: Looks like a messed-up install or deploy. You're not deploying a servlet or jsp jar in your own app, are you?

Comment: @DaveNewton...i have saved servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar in WebContent\WEB-INF\lib folder..is it sufficient??

Comment: You must *not* deploy your own servlet and jsp libraries. Remove them.

Comment: If required, just add in the classpath instead of copying them into WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: @DaveNewton the web container should ignore them if they were deployed with the application.

Comment: Maybe it *should*, but they certainly don't all share that opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i have saved servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar in WebContent\WEB-INF\lib folder..is it sufficient??

No. *Remove* them. If necessary, reconfigure your Eclipse project to set Tomcat as *Targeted Runtime*.

Read this thoroughly: [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project) Dropping arbitrary servlet container specific libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib` is one of most common beginner's mistakes in order to "solve" compilation problems on JSP/Servlet specific APIs which they faced in an IDE. It would make your webapp to run correctly *only* on the container where those libraries originated from, not on containers of different makes/versions.